# how to automatically run an Outlook macro?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, macros

i have developed an outlook macro and want this macro to run automatically without any prompt or mail from the user whether the outlook is on or not.

```
Private Declare Sub keybd_event Lib "user32" (ByVal bVk As Byte, ByVal _
 bScan As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)
Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
Private Const KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = &H2
Private Const VK_SNAPSHOT = &H2C
Private Const VK_MENU = &H12
Private Const SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED = 3
Private Declare Function ShowWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nCmdShow As Long) As Long
Private Const SW_MAXIMIZE = 3
Private Const SW_MINIMIZE = 6
Private Const SW_NORMAL = 1
Private Sub Application_Reminder(ByVal Item As Object)

If TypeName(Item) = "TaskItem" Then
    Dim myItem As TaskItem
    Set myItem = Item
    If myItem.Subject = "run macro Mail_workbook_Outlook_1" Then

        Call Mail_workbook_Outlook_1   '...your macro name here

    End If
End If
End Sub
Sub Mail_workbook_Outlook_1()
    ChDrive ("D:")
    ChDir ("D:\Eclipse\Workspaces\struts\Sonar\src\report")

    'Shell ("cmd.exe /S /K" & "java D:\Eclipse\Workspaces\struts\Sonar\src\reportOpenBrowser")

    'Const exeCmd = "java OpenBrowser"
    'Shell ("java OpenBrowser")

    Dim sdkCommand As String

    sdkCommand = "java Orange "
    Shell ("cmd.exe /c" & sdkCommand)

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = "check"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Orange "
        .Body = "Hi all " _
                & "PFB the status of Sonar report for Trunk"
        .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
        'You can add other files also like this
        .Attachments.Add ("d:\\Orange .jpg")
        .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<br>Orange REPORT:<br>" _
                & "<br><img src='d:\\Orange .jpg'" & "width='900' height='600'><br>" _
                & "Orange .<br>" _
                & "google.com" _
                & "<br>Regards,<br>Gaurav</font></span>"
        .Send   'or use .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: its possible to schedule an Excel macro so why not an Outlook macro

Comment: I am using Outlook 2010

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `/autorun` switch:

```
outlook.exe /autorun <macroname>
```

For example, create the following in Visual Basic Editor (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>):

```
Sub Hello()
    MsgBox "Hello World!"
End Sub
```

Create a shortcut on your desktop that has a target of:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\OFFICE11\OUTLOOK.EXE"  /autorun hello
```

Double-click on the shortcut and you'll be greeted with a message when you start Outlook.

Note that the path to `outlook.exe` may vary depending on your version and installation.

---

You can also define a `Application_Startup` macro that should run each time Outlook starts:

```
Private Sub Application_Startup() 

    MsgBox "Welcome, " & Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").CurrentUser 

    Application.ActiveExplorer.WindowState = olMaximized 

End Sub
```

The above is from the [Microsoft Developer Reference site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869298%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

You may have to configure your security settings for this to work:

```
File -> Options -> Trust Center -> Trust Center Settings -> Macro Settings -> Enable All
```

Note that I don't have Outlook 2010 to confirm the above :-)

Comment: Sir the new outlook window pops up but the macro does not run automatically

Comment: @GauravSood - I've added a very basic example which I can confirm works on Outlook 2003 (yes, 2003 - don't laugh). If that works, but your script doesn't then it's an issue with your script.

Comment: @garethTheRed, the security in Outlook 2003 did permit this, but for newer versions its not that easy. Then again, Gaurav Sood did not provide which outlook version he is using.

Comment: Sorry for that i am using Outlook 2010

Comment: Sorry to say but the code doesn't work for outlook 2010

Comment: @GauravSood - I've added to my answer.

Comment: @garethTheRed sir but this would only run the macro if there is no active instance of Outlook.
If there is an instance running, it only opens a new Outlook window but won't run the macro.

Comment: Instead of compromising your security settings, you can self sign your macro by running selfcert.exe, installing the certificate at the trusted root certification - local computer, reopening outlook and chosing always trust this publisher (or if it doesn't pop up on outlook initial load manually press alt-f11 and then choose always trust this publisher when it pops up).

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible. You cannot run an outlook macro without running outlook, in the same way that you cannot play a cd without cd-player.

Comment: its possible to schedule an Excel macro so why not an Outlook macro

Comment: You say: to run an outlook even if outlook is not running. That is not possible. By scheduling a macro, you start outlook first, so outlook is always running for this macro. Do note that macro's work very differently for outlook compared to excel, compared to word.

Comment: yes it does that's why i am asking how can we autorun the outlook macro